# How do you use pandas.DataFrame columns as index, columns, and values?

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

I can't seem to figure out how to ask this question in a searchable way, but I feel like this is a simple question.

Given a pandas Dataframe object, I would like to use one column as the index, one column as the columns, and a third column as the values.

For example:

```
   a   b   c
0  1  dog  2 
1  1  cat  1
2  1  rat  6
3  2  cat  2
4  3  dog  1
5  3  cat  4
```

---

I would like to user column 'a' as my index values, column 'b' as my columns, and column 'c' as the values for each row/column and fill with 0 for missing values (if possible).  For example...

```
   dog   cat   rat
1   2     1     6
2   0     2     0
3   1     4     0
```

This would be an 'a' by 'b' matrix with 'c' as the filling values

Comment: Sounds like you want [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html).  See [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reshaping.html) on "reshaping and pivot tables".

Comment: You could take a look at "dataframe.groupby" (not quite the same as `pivot_table`, but an interesting method) and "dataframe.reindex" methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's (almost) exactly as you phrase it:

```
df.pivot_table(index="a", columns="b", values="c", fill_value=0)
```

gives

```
b  cat  dog  rat
a               
1    1    2    6
2    2    0    0
3    4    1    0
```

HTH

Comment: You could pass `fill_value=0` to fill the missing values, too.

Answer (score 1):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reshaping.html

Starting with the example dataframe you give,

```
df.pivot(index='a', columns='b', values='c')
```

will produce pretty much exactly the output you want.

FWIW, df.melt() is the opposite transformation.